# How to handle overset text in java using the printf method

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I want a way to format output in java in this fashion:

Row entry  Text which is overset and 
             plays nice and creates new

         row automatically.

Row entry  Blah more neat input

Essentially, what I am having trouble with is using the printf method to output multiple rows of text while not advancing to a new line overall. The current code I'm using looks something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s",columnOneEntries[i],columnTwoText[i]);
}
```

Is there anyway to format my text like this using the printf method and a for loop? Or is there another method I shall have to use?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what your `columnOneEntries` and `columnTwoText` contain in your code. Maybe you can somehow modify the following idea to fit your data model.

```
    final String format = "%-10s %-10s%n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String[] wrappedLines = wrapTextToColumn(columnTwoText[i], 10);
        System.out.printf(format, columnOneEntries[i], wrappedLines[0]);
        for (int j = 1; j < wrappedLines.length; j++) {
            System.out.printf(format, "", wrappedLines[j]);
        }
    }
```

I understood that you were already able to break your text into multiple rows, so I haven’t done that. To use the code as-is, you would have to provide the `wrapTextToColumn` method.